# Using Centos is it possible to make a repo for node.js?

Tags: centos, node.js, repository

**Background:** I'm using CentOS 7.4.

I created a repo file for nginx which should make it easier to keep updated.

Inside `etc/nginx` I created a folder `yum.repos.d` and inside of that folder I inluded the file `nginx.repo`.

Inside of the file I included these lines.

```
[nginx]
name=nginx repo
baseurl=http://nginx.org/packages/centos/$releasever/$basearch/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
```

**Question:** Can I do something similar for node.js?  I can't find anything online.

**My current system**:

Step 1) Check online to determine the latest version. https://nodejs.org/en/

Step 2) Compare it against my installed version, `node -v`

Step 3) If I need to update use `nvm install lts/* --reinstall-packages-from=node`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That "works" for nginx not because *you* created the repository, but because *nginx* did.

In the case of Node.js, they also have created repositories and posted [instructions](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#enterprise-linux-and-fedora) on their web site.